# How to set active Spring profile with web parameter

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm working on a legacy Servlet app, where I'm taking Spring to help (not Spring MVC). The Spring configuration is working fine at the moment and I can set the active profile either by command line or programmatically.[This blog post states](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/) that the active Spring profile can be set as a web parameter also. However, I'm unable to make this option work.

I've simply tried to make a request to the servlet as `localhost://foo?spring.profiles.active=foo`, but this does not work as expected.

**What is the correct way of passing the web parameter for the active Spring profile? Is this something Spring MVC specific?**

Comment: Spring needs to know the profile when the application context is being constructed - i.e. during web application startup. The *Web parameter* method refers to context parameter set via `web.xml` - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L12 .

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Pavel. Seems like I'll have to use the profiles in a less dynamic way then. Please, post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring needs to know the profile when the application context is being constructed - i.e. during web application startup. The *Web parameter* method refers to [context parameter set via web.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L12):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>development</param-value>
</context-param>
```